# How to process pointclouds remotely, on workstation?

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, depth-registered, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I would like to run the [PCL People Detection Code](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pcl/html/people_2apps_2main__ground__based__people__detection_8cpp_source.html) for the Kinect of my TurtleBot. However I want to do most of the 'work' on my (more capable) workstation, rather than the TurtleBot's netbook, to speed up things considerably.

1. So **how do I run** openni_launch/openni.launch (or rgdb_launch/kinect_frames.launch?) **such that it does no processing**, but just publishes raw data? I have looked into the launch files and noticed that a lot of processing args are set to true by default like [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/blob/hydro-devel/launch/openni.launch#L41-L48) and [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rgbd_launch/blob/hydro-devel/launch/includes/processing.launch.xml#L13-L21) for example. So do I just set the ones that I don't need to false?
2. Having set the above args to false, and desiring to move the task of processing to my workstation, now I assume I have to, *from my workstation*, subscribe to this 'raw topic' (published to by the Kinect), retrieve the raw data, and do the processing (**whatever the above args do**) on the workstation. How would I go about doing that? I can't find the source code where these args are defined (in functions or whatever) and used!

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**:
Based on my [research](http://answers.ros.org/question/31831/how-do-you-use-depth_image_proc/) this is what I now run:

1. `rosrun openni_launch openni.launch` with all processing modules turned off. The following are the relevant (not all) camera topics active.

   /camera/depth/camera_info
   /camera/depth/image_raw
   /camera/depth_registered/camera_info
   /camera/depth_registered/image_raw
   /camera/rgb/camera_info
   /camera/rgb/image_raw
2. `ROS_NAMESPACE=camera/rgb rosrun image_proc image_proc`

   `ROS_NAMESPACE=camera/depth_registered rosrun image_proc image_proc`

The above two, according to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc), should give me the required topics - rgb/image_rect_color and depth_registered/image_rect - I need for converting to rgb pointclouds according to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#depth_image_proc.2BAC8-point_cloud_xyzrgb).

3. Before converting to pointcloud though, I convert to metric by `rosrun nodelet nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera/camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond`
4. Finally, I run `rosrun nodelet nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera/camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond`.

**Now here's the problem:** I do get the required /camera/depth_registered/points topic *active*, but I do NOT have any information on it, as evinced by a `rostopic echo`. **Am I converting incorrectly?**

**EDIT 2** I have realized that running image_proc for camera/rgb 'works' because the topics it publishes to actually have infomation being published onto it; however, for camera/depth_registered, the topic being published to i.e. **/camera/depth_registered/image_rect, has no information on it**. As a result, the next step i.e. running depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb would not work as it subscribes to an *empty topic*.

P.S. @bhaskara I know you are familiar with this (https://gist.github.com/bhaskara/2400165) so could you help me? @derekjchow you too please :)

Thanks guys!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152816/how-to-process-pointclouds-remotely,-on-workstation?/) by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The preferred method for sending Kinect data over WiFi is to send the depth image, then convert to a point cloud on the processing PC.

In your situation set up distributed ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines), then run "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" on the turtlebot.

On your host PC, you can run [depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) to convert from a depth image to a point cloud message.

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oswinium](https://answers.ros.org/users/11826/oswinium/) on 2014-04-17**:
So do I have to set the processing modules to "false" when I run openni.launch on the turtlebot?